# como dibujar ruta en un mapa con mapsforge?

Tags: android, map

Necesito dibujar rutas de un punto a otro con la `latitud` y `longitud` de dichos puntos en una mapa con la [librería mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) o si hay otra que por favor me la indiquen. Saludos

Comment: Pablo, aún deseas un ejemplo con MapsForge?

Comment: La idea es usar mapas offline, por eso pregunta por mapsforge y no de google maps

Answer (score 3):

Si trabajas con Android la puedes usar Google Maps, y puedes usar la clase **PolylineOptions** para crear la ruta entre dos puntos, por ejemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Dibuja marcadores.
    LatLng berlin = new LatLng(52.5243700   , 13.4105300);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(berlin).title("Berlin!"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.5105300, 14.50)).title("my home!"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(berlin));

 //Dibuja trayectoria.
 PolylineOptions line=
            new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(52.5243700,13.4105300),
                    new LatLng(52.5405300, 13.90),
                    new LatLng(53.1405300, 14.11),
                    new LatLng(53.5105300, 14.50))
                    .width(5).color(Color.RED);
    mMap.addPolyline(line);

}
```

Se definen dos marcadores y los puntos de la trayectoria, los cuales se mostraran en el mapa de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]